# Android SearchView: Modify search query on submit

Tags: android, searchview

I want to prepend a tag to the query for further use, without it appearing in the SearchView.

I tried to use setQuery() in the OnQueryTextListener but it doesn't put the tag in the query passed to the results activity. Also, when the user presses the "back" button from the results activity the tag is showing the SearchView field.

```
private OnQueryTextListener searchQueryListener = new OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

       searchView.setQuery(myTag + query,false);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        return true;
    }

};
```

Comment: Where are you pulling the data from: your own DB or third party content provider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you return `true` in `onQueryTextSubmit` you can handle the query yourself.